# How to use orderBy with Laravel 6 LazyCollection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

It's been a few days since the Laravel released its latest version 6. I am trying to implement Laravel LazyCollection instead of the normal Collection class.

Following line works-

```
Drug::where('deactive',0)->orderBy('code')->get();
```

And when I use

```
Drug::cursor()->where('deactive',0)->orderBy('code')->get();
```

I get an error `Method Illuminate\Support\LazyCollection::orderBy does not exist.`

Can anyone help me how to use OrderBy with LazyCollection?

**UPDATE**

After getting the answer here is the correct syntax of above query

```
Drug::cursor()->where('deactive',0)->sortBy('code');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offcourse, `orderBy` method is Query builder method. You can use `sortBy` as defined in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-sortby)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

```
Drug::where('deactive',0)->orderBy('code')->cursor();
```